I can't grab an element with querySelector with this attribute xlink:href=""
As the title says. I tried CSS.escape, used *=. This an attribute of an image element in Messenger.com. This is the attribute:
xlink:href="https://scontent.fmnl30-3.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/465963771_544837275103647_4349826739070598419_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_s100x100_tt6&_nc_cat=105&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=b70caf&_nc_eui2=AeEE5u8FlX9KtW7o_4a1fcWzQWyJI-PzqL9BbIkj4_Oov6uILnLZg6T1c8o-T2A485rybU_gN9fnXxXiRImyJhV6&_nc_ohc=WrSpzvLT1H8Q7kNvgESzF8i&_nc_zt=23&_nc_ht=scontent.fmnl30-3.fna&oh=03_Q7cD1QHLwyfkg9vNTc79uL6_mfOkWFpf2y2DCqNFF0KdUo0goA&oe=677A81BA"

I'm expecting for an element to be selected because it exists in the DOM. An interesting finding is when the element is inspected, it seems like the href attribute is an object instead of a string. I never encountered something like this before.
Solved by ChatGPT, it has something to do with XML namespace.
const namespace = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
const images = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("image")).filter(
    (el) => el.getAttributeNS(namespace, "href") === "url"
);
console.log(images);

However, please answer if you have an additional information, it might help others :)

Please visit [ask]

It's difficult, if not impossible, to help with this without seeing the relevant html.

ManuelMB got the answer from ChatGPT an hour before you did . Or is ManuelMB really ChatGPT?

@zer00ne I am not ChatGPT , I saw what he said: "Solved by ChatGPT ...."  (But didn't works) and then I publish my answer.

@zer00ne Did you mean I should not answer the question and instead leave my answer as a comment?. I will do it if I did previously wrong, sorry I didn't want break the forum rules

const namespace = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
const images = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('img')).filter(
(el) => el.getAttributeNS(namespace, "href") === "url"
);
console.log(images);

@ManuelMB hello ChatGPT did you know this site has banned you?

Stack Overflow is sinking. And the fault, of course, is (especially) ChatGPT's. StackOverflow must adapt to the fact that ChatGPT exists, denying it is a mistake, and in this case a user has received a solution from ChatGPT that was not exactly correct and my answer solved his problem.
